# format the page showing files of a directory of a website?

Tags: web, view, directory

Can I format the page showing files of a directory of a website?

Comment: Yes. Kinda depends on the circumstance though...

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can buddy :)

Seriously, please better specify your question. Do you mean something like getting a directory index from other websites or doing it in your own ?

For other websites, it depends on the their web server configuration. For your web server, if you are using apache, you could set the option Indexes to do that.

Answer (score 0):

**mod_autoindex** should do the trick.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_autoindex.html

Comment: @SpyrosP is correct: you need to explain your requirements better. I made the assumption you are using Apache's directory listing.